# Using https only when user is logged in not otherwise in web app

Tags: apache, security, tomcat, web-applications, https

I have a web application with servlets and jsps running on `tomcat`. I have enabled the tomcat to use `https` for all the users/visitors. I want to know if there is a way I can disable the `https` for users who are not logged in and are just browsing through the application.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching by a Tomcat setting to do that, the answer is no. If you open a port https/ssl security, you opened it for everyone (the only exception is if you intent to use client authentication using ssl client certificates, that a guess is not the case here).

However, you can check if the user is accessing using https (using HttpSerlvetRequest.isSecure()) and send him back to http with a redirect, or change all page links to starts with 'http', if he is not logged in. That will make sure that any link the user clicks will send him back to http.